# missing number from two squence

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I findout missing number from two sequence using bash script

from example I have file which contain following data

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 5
2 1
2 3
2 5
```

output : missing numbers are

```
1 4
2 2
2 4
```

Comment: If the sequence starts with `1 2` do you consider `1 1` is missing? or if it starts with `2 1` ?

Answer (score 3):

This awk one-liner gives the requested output for the specified input:

```
$ awk '$2!=l2+1&&$1==l1{for(i=l2+1;i<$2;i++)print l1,i}{l1=$1;l2=$2}' file
1 4
2 2
2 4
```

Answer (score 2):

a solution using grep:

```
printf "%s\n" {1..2}" "{1..5} | grep -vf file
```

Comment: Now I see where [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23363003/1983854) came from :)