# How to produce cartesian product in bash?

Tags: bash, seq

I want to produce such file (cartesian product of `[1-3]X[1-5]`):

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
3 5
```

I can do this using nested loop like:

```
for i in $(seq 3) 
do
  for j in $(seq 5)
  do
      echo $i $j
  done
done
```

is there any solution without loops?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Combine two [brace expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)!

```
$ printf "%s\n" {1..3}" "{1..5}
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
3 5
```

This works by using a single brace expansion:

```
$ echo {1..5}
1 2 3 4 5
```

and then combining with another one:

```
$ echo {1..5}+{a,b,c}
1+a 1+b 1+c 2+a 2+b 2+c 3+a 3+b 3+c 4+a 4+b 4+c 5+a 5+b 5+c
```

Comment: does {1..3} expand by shell?

Comment: Yes, `{1..3}` is same as `seq 3` or `seq 1 3`, just that it comes with shell.

Comment: is there any other using paste?

Comment: Not that I know, and I don't see the need. You can maybe use `echo {1..3}" "{1..5} | xargs -n 2`.

Comment: why does eg `echo {1..2}{3..4}` produce the full elm cross product `13 14 23 24` , as opposed to  `1 23 24` or `13 23 4`?

Comment: For those looking for discrete elements, e.g. `printf "%s\n" {a,e,z}" "{x,9,u}`

Answer (score 14):

A shorter (but hacky) version of Rubens's answer:

```
join -j 999999 -o 1.1,2.1 file1 file2
```

Since the field 999999 most likely does not exist it is considered equal for both sets and therefore `join` have to do the Cartesian product. It uses O(N+M) memory and produces output at 100..200 Mb/sec on my machine.

I don't like the "shell brace expansion" method like `echo {1..100}x{1..100}` for large datasets because it uses O(N*M) memory and can when used careless bring your machine to knees. It is hard to stop because ctrl+c does not interrupts brace expansion which is done by the shell itself.

Comment: This is the most generic solution as it works with files and not just a sequence of numbers

Comment: The `-j` command is GNU core util only. POSIX needs a field specification for each file... Even shorter still: `join -j 999 <(seq 3) <(seq 5)` to produce the OP's output.

Answer (score 10):

The best alternative for cartesian product in bash is surely -- as pointed by @fedorqui -- to use parameter expansion. However, in case your input that is not *easily producible* (i.e., if `{1..3}` and `{1..5}` does not suffice), you could simply use `join`.

For example, if you want to peform the cartesian product of two *regular files*, say "a.txt" and "b.txt", you could do the following. First, the two files:

```
$ echo -en {a..c}"\tx\n" | sed 's/^/1\t/' > a.txt
$ cat a.txt
1    a    x
1    b    x
1    c    x

$ echo -en "foo\nbar\n" | sed 's/^/1\t/' > b.txt
$ cat b.txt
1    foo
1    bar
```

Notice the `sed` command is used to prepend each line with an identifier. The identifier must be the same for all lines, **and** for all files, so the `join` will give you the cartesian product -- instead of putting aside some of the resultant lines. So, the `join` goes as follows:

```
$ join -j 1 -t $'\t' a.txt b.txt | cut -d $'\t' -f 2-
a    x    foo
a    x    bar
b    x    foo
b    x    bar
c    x    foo
c    x    bar
```

After both files are joined, `cut` is used as an alternative to remove the column of "1"s formerly prepended.

Comment: what u write as join is really a join (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28relational_algebra%29#Joins_and_join-like_operators) i do not need join. what i want is cartesian product (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: @طاهر Well, when you join each and every row from one table with the rows from another table, i.e., when you do a [*cross join*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join), your output is a cartesian product.

Comment: The benefit of this solution is that bash doesn't inherently allow variables to be used in brace expansions. You can use variables in brace expansion with eval, but then you're using eval.