# concatenate two lists from two files into one file

Tags: bash, while-loop, readline

I have 2 lists which I am trying to combine/join/merge using a bash script.

List 1

```
file1-1
file1-2
file1-3
file1-4
```

and so on

List 2 contains

```
file2-1
file2-2
file2-3
file2-4
```

and so on

I'm try to get an output something like this

```
file1-1:file2-1
file1-2:file2-1
file1-3:file2-1
file1-4:file2-1
file1-1:file2-2
file1-2:file2-2
file1-3:file2-2
file1-4:file2-2
file1-1:file2-3
file1-2:file2-3
file1-3:file2-3
file1-4:file2-3
```

and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to produce cartesian product in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363003/how-to-produce-cartesian-product-in-bash)

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna Not really the same as that is creating them from a set of values created in the production part, not making the coupling from files, which requires a different approach than a simple printf statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**merge.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line2; do
  while read line1; do
    printf "$line1:$line2\n";
  done < file1.txt;
done < file2.txt;
```

**output**

```
$ ./merge.sh 
file1-1:file2-1
file1-2:file2-1
file1-3:file2-1
file1-4:file2-1
file1-1:file2-2
file1-2:file2-2
file1-3:file2-2
file1-4:file2-2
file1-1:file2-3
file1-2:file2-3
file1-3:file2-3
file1-4:file2-3
file1-1:file2-4
file1-2:file2-4
file1-3:file2-4
file1-4:file2-4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this with `GNU Parallel`:

```
parallel -k -a file1 -a file2 echo

file1-1 file2-1
file1-1 file2-2
file1-1 file2-3
file1-1 file2-4
file1-2 file2-1
file1-2 file2-2
file1-2 file2-3
file1-2 file2-4
file1-3 file2-1
file1-3 file2-2
file1-3 file2-3
file1-3 file2-4
file1-4 file2-1
file1-4 file2-2
file1-4 file2-3
file1-4 file2-4
```

Or this:

```
parallel -k -a file2 -a file1 echo {2}:{1}

file1-1:file2-1
file1-2:file2-1
file1-3:file2-1
file1-4:file2-1
file1-1:file2-2
file1-2:file2-2
file1-3:file2-2
file1-4:file2-2
file1-1:file2-3
file1-2:file2-3
file1-3:file2-3
file1-4:file2-3
file1-1:file2-4
file1-2:file2-4
file1-3:file2-4
file1-4:file2-4
```

Comment: They want them the other way round, obviously a simple fix but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ Picky! ;-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

join on a fake field and trim it afterwards

```
join -t: <(sed 's/^/:/' file1) <(sed 's/^/:/' file2) | cut -c2-
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternative uses `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=":"}
     { 
        while(getline line < "file1"){  print line,$0  }
     } 
     close("file1")
' file2
```