# moving sql logic to backend - bash

Tags: bash, shell, perl, awk

One of the sql logic is moving to backend and I need to generate a report using shell scripting.
For understanding, I'm making it simple as follows.

My input file - sales.txt (id, price, month)

```
101,50,2019-10
101,80,2020-08
101,80,2020-10
201,100,2020-09
201,350,2020-10
```

The output should be for 6 months window for each id e.g t1=2020-07 and t2=2020-12

```
101,50,2020-07
101,80,2020-08
101,80,2020-09
101,80,2020-10
101,80,2020-11
101,80,2020-12
201,100,2020-09
201,350,2020-10
201,350,2020-11
201,350,2020-12
```

For id `101`, though there is no entry for 2020-07, it should take from the immediate previous month value that is available in the sales file.
So the price=50 from 2019-10 is used for 2020-07.

For `201`, the first entry itself is from 2020-09, so 2020-08 and 2020-07 are not applicable.
Wherever there are gaps the immediate previous month value should be propagated.

I'm trying to use awk to solve this problem, I'm creating a reusable script util.awk like below
to generate the missing values, pipe it to sort command and then again use the util.awk for final output.

util.awk

```
function get_month(a,b,t1) { return strftime("%Y%m",mktime(a " " b t1)) } 
BEGIN { ss=" 0 0 0 "; ts1=" 1 " ss; ts2=" 35 " ss ; OFS="," ; x=1 } 
{ 
  tsc=get_month($3,$4,ts1);
  if ( NR>1 && $1==idp )
  {
  if( tsc == tsp) { print $1,$2,get_month($3,$4,ts1); x=0  }
  else { for(i=tsp; i < tsc; i=get_month(j1,j2,i) )  
         { 
       j1=substr(i,1,4); j2=substr(i,5,2); 
           print $1,tpr,i;
         }
       }
   }

  tsp=get_month($3,$4,ts2);  
  idp=$1;
  tpr=$2;
  if(x!=0) print $1,$2,tsc
  x=1;
  
}
```

But it is running infinitely `awk -F"[,-]" -f utils.awk sales.txt`

Though I tried in awk, I welcome other answers as well that would work in bash environment.

Comment: what do you mean by `sql logic is moving to backend`? when I hear/see `backend` I think of a database server, but there's nothing in the question related to a (sql) database ... ??  how many lines in your input file (`sales.txt`)?

Comment: when I run the code it generates: `101,50,201910`, `101,50,201911`, `101,50,196912`, with that last one (`101,50,196912`) repeating over and over and over (infinite loop?); the `196912` looks like epoch time minus 1 sec, which is likely happening due to a missing/null/empty/invalid arg to `mktime()` (???); first time through the `for` loop, `j1`, `j2` are undefined so not sure what that's doing for the `for` increment comonent; the `for` loop has an increment of `i=get_month(j1,j2,i)` where `i` is a 6-digit number like `YYYYMM`, which doesn't seem to be a valid arg for the function (???) ...

Comment: ... I'd suggest adding some `print` commands at strategic locations to show your variables ... from that you should be able to get some ideas as to where the logic is going off the rails; to keep the main call from scrolling off the screen consider: `awk -F"[,-]" -f utils.awk sales.txt | head -100` (adjusting the `head` arg to display enough info for several loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question a bit. The following awk should do the trick

```
$ awk -v t1="2020-07" -v d="6" '
     function next_month(d,a) { 
         split(d,a,"-"); a[2]==12?a[1]++ && a[2]=1 : a[2]++
         return sprintf("%0.4d-%0.2d",a[1],a[2])
     } 
     BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";t2=t1; for(i=1;i<=d;++i) t2=next_month(t2)}
     {k[$1]}
     ($3<t1){a[$1,t1]=$2}
     (t1 <= $3 && $3 < t2) { a[$1,$3]=$2 }
     END{ for (key in k) {
            p=""; t=t1; 
            for(i=1;i<=d;++i) { 
               if(p!="" || (key,t) in a) print key, ((key,t) in a ? p=a[key,t] : p), t
               t=next_month(t)
            }
          }
     }' input.txt
```

We implemented a straightforward function `next_month` that computes the next month based on a format `YYYY-MM`. Based on the duration of `d` months, we compute the time-period that should be shown in the `BEGIN` block. The time-period of interest is `t1 <= t < t2`.

Every time we read a record/line, we keep track of the key that he's been processed and store it in the array `k`. This way we know which key has been seen up to this point.

for all the times before the time-period of interest, we store the value in an array `a` with index `(key,t1)`, while for all other times, we store the value in the array `a` with key `(key,$3)`.

When the file is fully processed, we just cycle over all keys and print the output. We used a bit of logic, to check whether or not the month was listed in the original file.

**Note:** the output will be per key sorted in time, but the key will not appear in the same order as in the original file.

Comment: yes it works.. and thank you so much for your response.. The END section is bit tricky.. but will spend sometime to understand..

Answer (score 2):

General plan:

- assumption: `sales.txt` is already sorted (numerically) by the first column
- user provides the min->max date range to be displayed (`awk` variables `mindt` and `maxdt`)
- for a distinct `id` value we'll load all prices and dates into an array (`prices[]`)
- dates will be used as the indices of an associative array to store prices (`prices[YYYY-MM]`)
- once we've read all records for a given `id` ...
- sort the `prices[]` array by the indices (ie, sort by `YYYY-MM`)
- find the price for the max date less than `mindt` (save as `prevprice`)
- for each date between `mindt` and `maxdt` (inclusive), if we have a price then display it (and save as `prevprice`) else ...
- if we don't have a price but we do have a `prevprice` then use this `prevprice` as the current date's `price` (ie, fill the gap with the previous price)

One (GNU) `awk` idea:

```
mindate='2020-07'
maxdate='2020-12'

awk -v mindt="${mindate}" -v maxdt="${maxdate}" -v OFS=',' -F',' ' 

# function to add "months" (number) to "indate" (YYYY-MM)

function add_month(indate,months) {

    dhms="1 0 0 0"                                     # default day/hr/min/secs
    split(indate,arr,"-")
    yr=arr[1]
    mn=arr[2]

    return strftime("%Y-%m", mktime(arr[1]" "(arr[2]+months)" "dhms))
}

# function to print the list of prices for a given "id"

function print_id(id) {

    if ( length(prices) == 0 )                         # if prices array is empty then do nothing (ie, return)
       return

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"               # sort prices[] array by index in ascending order

    for ( i in prices )                                # loop through indices (YYYY-MM)
        { if ( i < mindt )                             # as long as less than mindt
             prevprice=prices[i]                       # save the price
          else
             break                                     # no more pre-mindt indices to process
        }

    for ( i=mindt ; i<=maxdt ; i=add_month(i,1) )     # for our mindt - maxdt range
        { if ( !(i in prices) && prevprice )          # if no entry in prices[], but we have a prevprice, then ...
             prices[i]=prevprice                      # set prices[] to prevprice (ie, fill the gap)

          if ( i in prices )                          # if we have an entry in prices[] then ...
             { prevprice=prices[i]                    # update prevprice (for filling future gap) and ...
               print id,prices[i],i                   # print our data to stdout
             }
        }
}

BEGIN { split("",prices) }                             # pre-declare prices as an array

previd != $1 { print_id(previd)                        # when id changes print the prices[] array, then ...
               previd=$1                               # reset some variables for processing of the next id and ...
               prevprice=""
               delete prices                           # delete the prices[] array
             }

             { prices[$3]=$2 }                         # for the current record create an entry in prices[]

END   { print_id(previd) }                             # flush the last set of prices[] to stdout
' sales.txt
```

**NOTE**: This assumes `sales.txt` is sorted (numerically) by the first field; if this is not true then the last line should be changed to `' <(sort -n sales.txt)`

This generates:

```
101,50,2020-07
101,80,2020-08
101,80,2020-09
101,80,2020-10
101,80,2020-11
101,80,2020-12
201,100,2020-09
201,350,2020-10
201,350,2020-11
201,350,2020-12
```

Comment: @makp-fuso.. the file will be sorted  by id and date. your solution works now.. will test thoroughly