# Bash get all permutations of lines from two files concatenated without intervening whitespace?

Tags: bash

i making a proyect and i want to join to files using paste, but i want to do this

```
List1         List2
a               1
b               2
c               3

Result
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
```

Is there a way to get that result with paste?

Comment: If this is tagged `bash`, are you okay with answers that use bash builtins _instead_ of using `paste`?

Comment: not possible with `paste`, far as I can tell. You're really looking for the *set product* of the lines from both files, and that's not something `paste` is useful for. In all honesty, this sounds trivial to do with Python's `collections` module and sufficiently hard and slow in bash scripting to justify doing this bit in Python.

Comment: _nod_. `paste -d ''` would give you `a1` `b2` `c3`, which is the only thing it's designed to do. It's not a tool designed or documented to calculate cross products.

Comment: Hello @CharlesDuffy yes is inside a bash script, any alternative that is not paste?

Comment: Hello @MarcusMüller any example to do this on python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product ; as files can be read line-wise if `open`ed in text mode, you can directly pass `open("List1")` and `open("List2")` as arguments to `itertools.product(…)`

Answer (score 2):

Feeding the files in reverse order to `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[++cnt]=$1;next}{for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) print $1 a[i]}' f2 f1
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
```

---

Expanding on [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675223/7366100):

```
$ join -j 9999999 -o 1.1,2.1 f1 f2 | sed 's/ //'
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and two simple loops:

```
while read -r l1; do while read -r l2; do echo "$l1$l2"; done <list2; done <list1
```

Output:

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash, reading each file once:

```sh
mapfile -t list1 < file1
mapfile -t list2 < file2
brace_expr=$(IFS=,; printf '{%s}{%s}' "${list1[*]}" "${list2[*]}")
eval "printf '%s\n' $brace_expr"
```

**BUT** this is vulnerable to code injection: you'd better be 100% certain the contents of the files are safe.

Answer (score 0):

With python would you please try the following (as Marcus Müller comments):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import itertools

with open('list1', 'r') as f1:
    i1 = f1.read().splitlines()
with open('list2', 'r') as f2:
    i2 = f2.read().splitlines()
for v1, v2 in itertools.product(i1, i2):
    print(v1 + v2)
```